# Intent call action doesn't work on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I'm trying to start a call intent action on a device who has Marshmallow as OS, Using the same steps as usual (This is working on versions below):

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Open the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getString(R.string.connect_phone)));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the log I'm getting:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.app.calling, PID: 4250
>                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity
>   VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} }
>   from ProcessRecord{1618b01 4250:com.app.calling/u0a234} (pid=4250,
>   uid=10234) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
>                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3130)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1540)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:849)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:907)
>                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:919)
>                                                                        at
>   com.app.calling.activity.fragment.ConnectFragment$2.onGroupClick(ConnectFragment.java:44)
>                                                                        at
>   android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:676)
>                                                                        at
>   android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:654)
>                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3821)
>                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5841)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Again, this process is working fine in the previous version (Lollipop and kitkat)unfortunately isn't on Marshmallow, does anybody know why or what I'm missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beginning in android 6.0 (API 23), dangerous permissions must be declared in the manifest *AND* you must explicitly request that permission from the user. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups) list, `CALL_PHONE` is considered a dangerous permission.

Every time you perform an operation that requires a dangerous permission, you must check if that permission has been granted by the user. If it has not, you must request that it be granted. See [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on Android Developers.

Answer (score 26):

> Method to make call

```
public void onCall() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    "123");
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345678901")));
        }
    }
```

> Check permission

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case 123:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    onCall();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Call Permission Not Granted");
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bro What is the use of Second code Check permission, already you asked permission in First code and Android Manifest then do we need that?

Comment: The first code snippet: check if the permission has been previously granted and if it is not granted, prompt user to grant that permission. The second code snippet: check if the permission has now been granted and if it is, run the method onCall().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088812/how-to-do-call-intent-with-firebase-in-android-check-out-my-code-and-screensho

Comment: Check that question bruhhh, I did like what you said but still nothing works ,can you please check it and tell me

Answer (score 1):

For Marshmallow version and above you need to ask the permission at runtime not only in the manifest file. Here is the documentation:

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Hope it helps.